# What is the use of resetting your pay rank?

Tags: splatoon-2

When maxed in Profreshionnal, I had an option to 'reset my rank'

Thinking it would give me some bonuses or some straight cash, or at least tell me what it did, I hit it.

No popup to explain anything to gain or changes, and it just went to Profreshionnal 40.

Is there a use to resetting your rank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Splatoon_2/comments/mn01ja/what_will_happen_if_i_reset_my_rank_to/):

> It's there for players who want to play with lower level friends without having them be overwhelmed. Also, it's what a lot of players should do after an easy shift.

Comment: That was my theory. But it really sucks that there doesn't seem to be any benefit to do so.

Comment: Agree. I used to play a lot of Splatoon, but there are still things I really don't understand. +1 for still playing it!

Comment: Oh I just fell back in it this weekend because a Lets player I follow is currently LPing it (Chuggaaconroy) Guess I have to warmup for Splatoon 3 this summer too.